# VirtualMachine attach throws com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: 0 when using Open JDK 10.0.2

Tags: java, javaagents, java-attach-api

I am facing an issue when using the `com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine`Java API. My target application(Tomcat) is running using Oracle Hot Spot version 1.7.0_80. I am trying to connect that tomcat via dynamic attach  from another Java program (on the same machine) which is using Open JDK 10.0.2.  I am using the below code

```
...............
String agentPath = Agent.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
agentPath = convertFileSeparators(agentPath, File.separatorChar);
String agentInstallDir = agentPath.substring(0, agentPath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
System.out.println("My Java agent installed on the location :"+agentPath);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("MY_RELIC_HOME").append("=").append(agentInstallDir);
if (agentArgs != null) {
     sb.append(",").append(agentArgs);
}
com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine virtualMachine =  com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(vmID);
virtualMachine.loadAgent(agentPath, sb.toString());
.........
```

I am able to attach successfully to the target application , but getting the below exception in my attach program (running open JDK 10.0.2) after attach.

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: 0
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:104)
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:115)
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:139)
    at com.eg.agent.Agent.main(Agent.java:582)
```

The code on the line no 582 is `virtualMachine.loadAgent(agentPath, sb.toString());`.

If i run my attach program using Java 7 or 8, there is no exception and attach is success.

Why `com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: 0` exception occurs when using JDK 10 ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue , After looking the source code of `sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine` on both version of java 10 & 8. The Method loadAgentLibrary(...) is completely different between 10 & 8.

**Below code is from 1.8** which shows that the value of the `result` is zero means VMAttach is success.

```
private void loadAgentLibrary(String agentLibrary, boolean isAbsolute, String options)
    throws AgentLoadException, AgentInitializationException, IOException
{
    InputStream in = execute("load",
                             agentLibrary,
                             isAbsolute ? "true" : "false",
                             options);
    try {
        int result = readInt(in);
        if (result != 0) {
            throw new AgentInitializationException("Agent_OnAttach failed", result);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();

    }
}
```

**Below code is from java 10** in VM Attach is success when the value of the `result` is `"return code: 0"` (but in 1.8 it is simply `0`).

```
private void loadAgentLibrary(String agentLibrary, boolean isAbsolute, String options) 
    throws AgentLoadException, AgentInitializationException, IOException 
{ 
    String msgPrefix = "return code: "; 
    InputStream in = execute("load", 
                             agentLibrary, 
                             isAbsolute ? "true" : "false", 
                             options); 
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) { 
        String result = reader.readLine(); 
        if (result == null) { 
            throw new AgentLoadException("Target VM did not respond"); 
        } else if (result.startsWith(msgPrefix)) { 
            int retCode = Integer.parseInt(result.substring(msgPrefix.length())); 
            if (retCode != 0) { 
                throw new AgentInitializationException("Agent_OnAttach failed", retCode); 
            } 
        } else { 
            throw new AgentLoadException(result); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

In my case Java 7/8 code (Target Application) returns the `result` as `0`(which means VM Attach is success) to Java 10 code (VM Attach code), which expects the result should be `"return code: 0"`